# Name customization for attribute_of

Tags: soap, python-2.7, spyne

I'm playing with `attribute_of` and spyne 2.10 (very glad it's out). Let's consider following model:

```
class Product(ComplexModel):
    id = complex.XmlAttribute(primitive.Uuid)
    edition = primitive.Unicode
    edition_id = complex.XmlAttribute(primitive.Uuid, attribute_of='edition')
```

That gives results like:

```
<product id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
    <edition edition_id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">My edition</edition>
</product>
```

How to customize `edition_id`'s name for results like `<edition id="..."/>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2.10, Spyne does not support this.

I can't think of an easy workaround as it'd require writing method_call and method_return_document events as well as wsdl events to patch the wsdl manually.

However, if you can write tests for it, I'll see what I can do for the 2.11.

Comment: Hi, please have a look at https://github.com/plq/spyne/blob/72665943092378a6d49460e21adeb95845dd4de5/examples/xml_utils.py#L78 and tell me what you think.